# How to do akka http request for oauth2 access_token

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am trying to request auth server to get access_token . I have a working curl command , but am unable to implement using Akka HTTP.

```
 curl -v -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET -k -X POST -d {} 'URL/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Scope'
```

or

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: Basic Base64(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)' --request POST URL/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=scope'
```

i am getting ***405 Method Not*** Allowed error while requesting using http.singleRequest

```
def getToken(url:String, user: String, pass: String, scope:String) = {

  Http()
    .singleRequest(
      Post(
        Uri(url),
        Map("grant_type" -> "client_credentials", "scope" -> s"$scope"),
      ).withHeaders(
        Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials(user, pass)),
      ),
    )

}
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code/config!

Comment: added the sample fn.

Comment: is it possible the URL that you use in the scala code does not match the URL that you use in the curl call?

Comment: Thanks Everyone, it worked now after adding entity using FromData. FormData
        .apply(
          Map(
            "grant_type" -> "client_credentials",
            "scope"      -> "scope",
          ),

Comment: Would you mind posting your code as an answer, so that we would as well learn where you have put this final line that solved the problem?

Comment: sure, James will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val request = HttpRequest(
  HttpMethods.POST,
  config.authDomain,
  entity = FormData
    .apply(
      Map(
        "grant_type" -> s"${config.grant_type}",
        "scope" -> s"${config.api_scope}",
      ),
    )
    .toEntity,
).withHeaders(Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials(config.access_id, config.access_secret)))
```